# Check two variables for undefined

Tags: javascript

JS:

```
  var ctoken = req.cookies.user;
  var stoken = req.session.passport.user;

  if(ctoken === 'undefined' || stoken === 'undefined'){
    return res.send('invalid token'); 
  }else{
    if (ctoken.split('_')[0] !== stoken) {
      return res.send('invalid token'); 
    }
  }
```

At

```
ctoken.split('_')[0]
```

an error is thrown :

```
cannot call split of undefined.
```

Why? This should not happen because of the `if` condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes :

```
if (ctoken === undefined || stoken === undefined) {
```

Maybe you were confused by a trend during which some programmers recommended to test using

```
if (typeof something === 'undefined') {
```

But the best test is to simply compare with `undefined`.

Comment: The first way is the best, but providing you are certain `undefined` has not been declared with a different value

Comment: @musefan In modern browsers you can't redefine `undefined`. And in the past the only right way to respond to a programmer redefining `undefined` was to slap him.

Comment: @dystroy: Bring back the slap I say! Also my Chrome is pretty modern, and you can [redefine it like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCPWt/), but it has to be a local (in scope) `var`, you are correct that you cannot redefine the original `undefined` keyword

Comment: You don't redefine it, you shadow it. It's true you can do that, but hardly without a dedicated effort and, more importantly, it can't leak in other modules.

Comment: Comparing with undefined is poor style anyway, but if you must, `typeof` is slightly more readable and robust.